# My MacBook Pro, High Sierra downloaded 13G last night while asleep

Tags: network, performance, high-sierra

The system was presumably closed at my workplace.

How can I find why ? Some light on those 13Gb ? How Activity Monitor finds those numbers ? I will be glad to provide more information while the computer is not yet shut down.
[image]

I have no automatic updates, last one was on 27 June, more than a week ago.

system.log is full of entries like:

```
Aug  4 11:59:23 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Aug  4 11:59:33 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[7132]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 11:59:33 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Aug  4 11:59:44 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[7133]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 11:59:44 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Aug  4 11:59:54 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[7134]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 11:59:54 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Aug  4 12:00:04 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[7135]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 12:00:04 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Aug  4 12:00:14 MacBook-Pro-de-... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[7136]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

During the night, when it should have slept - the laptop was very much alive:

```
Aug  4 00:53:44 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:53:51 MacBook-Pro syslogd[45]: ASL Sender Statistics
Aug  4 00:53:54 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3849]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:53:54 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:54:04 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3850]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:54:04 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:54:15 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3851]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:54:15 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:54:26 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3852]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:54:26 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 4 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 6 seconds.
Aug  4 00:54:36 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3853]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:54:36 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:54:47 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3854]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:54:47 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:54:57 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3855]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:54:57 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:55:07 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3856]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:55:07 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 2 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 8 seconds.
Aug  4 00:55:19 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd[3857]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Aug  4 00:55:19 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.touristd): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds.
Aug  4 00:55:28 MacBook-Pro systemstats[56]: assertion failed: 17A315i: systemstats + 641142 [8F334E9C-6F6C-3ED1-9251-D75E5C8E9EEC]: 0x5
```

Comment: Do you have automatic update enabled for any program or the system?

Comment: No, my colleagues suspect touristd or something

Comment: We have limited bandwidth for the moment, so this is really important.

Comment: touristd is responsible for the "New to Mac?" notification that pops out when you just starting to use your Mac. I suggest you install Little Snitch https://www.obdev.at/ and monitor the stats from there. You can see which app or process is generating so much data transfer.

Comment: @Liviu Might have been easier blocking it completely with Little Snitch

Comment: Little Snitch demands money after just 3 hours and it is hard to stop. Why use a gun when a knife suffice?

Answer (score 4):

It was `touristd` which restarts every few seconds and downloads more than 10M by minute. 
I do not know what it's doing, I tried to disable every Internet related option, but it kept turning on.

```
$ launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.touristd.plist 
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.touristd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
```

Reboot "Recovery OS"

```
csrutil enable --without fs --no-internal
```

Then reboot normally and

```
$ sudo mkdir /backup
Password:
$ sudo mkdir /backup/System
$ sudo mkdir /backup/System/Library/
$ sudo mkdir /backup/System/Library/LaunchAgents/
$ sudo mv /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.touristd.plist /backup/System/Library/LaunchAgents/
$ ll /backup/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.touristd.plist 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  897 Mar 28 03:55 /backup/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.touristd.plist
```

Reboot "Recovery OS"

```
csrutil enable
```

Comment: That’s painful. Excellent analysis and steps to disable sip and disable spthat daemon. I wonder if I need to file a bug to get an mom profile to disable that for work. Clearly an error condition and it won’t download that data once High Sierra ships.